# MySQL - Turning mm/dd/yyyy to unixtimestamp

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I have a field where users use a date picker to select a date.  The value gets saved as "mm/dd/yyyy".  I'm creating a query that needs to turn that into a timestamp.  I tried using:

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(po.dueToProduction, '%y%m%d'))
```

but results were returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument (format) of `STR_TO_DATE` is the input format which you specified as "mm/dd/yyyy"

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(po.dueToProduction, '%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Comment: Ugh - always the stupid little things that get me.  I"ll make as answer when I'm allowed.  Thanks.